# Responsive image in CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with CMS. I need to change css that the page could be responsive.
One of the div has data-height, data-weight and height, width in style in html that it looks like that

div class="classOf" id="idOf" data-width="755" data-height="125" style="width: 755px; height: 125px;"

I can't use my new css due to is not working if I select this id and change properties.
This is CMS so I can only console to append new css and js.

My question is how to neutralize this set properties on html and apply css with max-width:100%
that will work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your own customized css at the end of the html document, it will override any existing css file included before.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a moment to read:  [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Though I think you are on the right track with your answer, it would be beneficial if you could support it with a code sample or additional details that would benefit the OP.

Comment: Nope it wont override more over I have tried also this !important thing and it didn't worked

Comment: Could you provide the full document including all php?

Answer (score 0):

In your css add !important to the width attribute, it should over-ride the inline style.

Example:

```
 .classOf{
           width: 100% !important;
      }
```

Comment: How about over-riding the data attribute value.

Comment: Try: [data-width]{ width:100% !important; }

Comment: I just tried it on copepen should work. check it out http://codepen.io/Lumpyjuice/pen/XJXqdv. sorry about the previous broken link